# Using a Join with Grouped Data Rows

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have two tables, `invoices` and `deposits`.

They look a bit like this:

INVOICES

```
id    |    paymentType     |     grossTotal   |    dateTime
1     |         Cash       |        1000      |   UNIX TIME    
2     |         Card       |        1350      |   UNIX TIME   
3     |         Card       |        1250      |   UNIX TIME   
4     |         Card       |        750       |   UNIX TIME
```

DEPOSITS

```
id    |    paymentType     |       invNo      |    dateTime    |     amount
1     |         Cash       |         1        |    UNIX TIME   |       150
2     |         Card       |         2        |    UNIX TIME   |       350
```

The deposits are always past dates, and the invoice dates will be, for example `today`, so I want to determine the balance paid today on an invoice, ie, `invoices.grossTotal - deposits.amount`, and list by payment Type.

So, in the table example above, there is £850 would have been paid on  Invoice 1 and £1000 on invoice 2, this is simple to achieve with one or two rows of each, but when grouping payment types and deposit invoices I am stuck...

```
SELECT 
   invoices.id, 
   sum(grossTotal)-IFNULL(depositsCheck.previouslyPaid,0) as todayTotal, 
   depositsCheck.previouslyPaid, sum(grossTotal) as grossTotal  
FROM `invoices`    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(amount) as previouslyPaid, invNo 
    FROM deposits 
    GROUP BY invNo) depositsCheck ON depositsCheck.invNo=invoices.id 
GROUP BY  invoices.paymentType ORDER BY id DESC
```

The SQL Query above, will work for the item paid for with CASH, but not for the Card payments, because, grouping `invoices.paymentType` means that the `id` column from the `invoices` table is no longer correct, so the `JOIN` fails if this row has an `id` to which no deposit relates.

How can I run a query as above, but ensuring that I can `join` the `deposits` table on any instance of an invoice, grouped by payment type that matches the grouped column id records?

I am using mySql, so please post joins that MySql can do! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `GROUP BY`, you can only `SELECT` aggregates and the columns you have grouped on.

`invoices.id` is a column you tried to select, but did not group. I think you probably want to add this column to the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
   invoices.id, 
   sum(grossTotal)-IFNULL(depositsCheck.previouslyPaid,0) as todayTotal, 
   depositsCheck.previouslyPaid, sum(grossTotal) as grossTotal  
FROM `invoices`    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(amount) as previouslyPaid, invNo 
    FROM deposits 
    GROUP BY invNo) depositsCheck ON depositsCheck.invNo=invoices.id 
GROUP BY  invoices.paymentType, invoices.id ORDER BY id DESC
```

For the example tables you gave, it will probably give:

```
id    |    paymentType     |     grossTotal   |    dateTime   |   previouslyPaid
1     |         Cash       |        1000      |   UNIX TIME   |       150
2     |         Card       |        1350      |   UNIX TIME   |       350
3     |         Card       |        1250      |   UNIX TIME   |         0
4     |         Card       |        750       |   UNIX TIME   |         0
```

But in general, you will have something like:

```
id    |    paymentType     |     grossTotal   |    dateTime   |   previouslyPaid
1     |         Cash       |        1000      |   UNIX TIME   |       150
1     |         Card       |        1000      |   UNIX TIME   |       300
2     |         Cash       |        1350      |   UNIX TIME   |       350
2     |         Card       |        1350      |   UNIX TIME   |       350
```

Where you can see above, for invoice 1, 150 was paid in cash, and 300 was paid by card.

Comment: Ah, yes! You're right, but that returns too many rows, so I have wrapped the whole thing in another `SELECT` and grouped that by paymentType