# How can i make a table while fetch assoc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hello i'm a (beginning) php backend dev and i'm working on a dj panel  but it doesnt work the right way i tried as many things as i could but i cant get it to work..

```
    $active_ids = '1, 3, 4';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({$active_ids})";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);   

    $query2 = "SELECT dj, count(*) AS n FROM timetable WHERE dj IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY dj";
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>", $row['username'] ,"</td>";
            }

            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<td>", $row2['n'] ,"</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
```

this is what it shows

```
ZOMBOY
Hater
ZOMBOY2 3
1
1
```

and this is how it needs to become but i cant find a way to do it

```
ZOMBOY    3
Hater     1
ZOMBOY2   1
```

Comment: you need to do a `join` query in order to display results.

Comment: it's grouped so i dont know how to do it properly @Kamran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` instead to querying two table

```
$active_ids = '1, 3, 4';

$query = "SELECT u.username, count(*) AS n FROM users u, timetable tt WHERE u.id=tt.dj and u.id IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY tt.dj";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>", $row['username'] ,"</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['n'] ,"</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, but must be look [Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
$active_ids = '1, 3, 4';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({$active_ids})";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);   

$query2 = "SELECT dj, count(*) AS n FROM timetable WHERE dj IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY dj";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
$columnOne = Array();
$columnTwo = Array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $columnOne[]= $row['username'];
    }

    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            $columnTwo[] = row2['n'];
        }
    }
}
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<count($columnOne);$i++){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $columnOne[$i] . '</td><td>' . $columnTwo[$i] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: as i said  it's grouped so i dont know how to JOIN it properly

Comment: in page source have <table>,

Comment: second question is querry return any result

Comment: test the arrays `print_r ($columnOne);` `print_r ($columnTwo);`

Comment: it echo's array() array()

Comment: must be query result is empty

Comment: then dont use it, you said in your question `showing like that and this is how it needs to become but i cant find a way to do it` and I responded to what you say. Its other problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316472/using-a-join-with-grouped-data-rows

Answer (score 1):

You could try something such as this (Not quite as elegant as others):

```
# Escape your characters
$active_ids = "'1', '3', '4'";

# Tidy up the querys to reduce the change of reserved words being used
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN ({$active_ids});";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);   
$query2 = "SELECT `dj`, COUNT(*) AS n FROM `timetable` WHERE `dj` IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY `dj`";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

# Count your results
$c1 = count($result); 
$c2 = count($result2);
#Set the counter to be the larger of the 2
$counter = (($c1 > $c2) ? $c1 : $c2);
if ($result->num_rows > 0 && $result2->num_rows > 0)
{
    # Print the table opener
    print '<table class="your_class">';
    # Loop through your results
    for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++)
    {
        # Print the data needed
        print '<tr><td>' . $result[$i]['username'] . '</td><td>' . $result2[$i]['n'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    # End the table
    print '</table>';
}
```