# Get all id's from table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'd like to echo all ID's from the user table but I can't get it to work.  I tried this below and searched some stacks but I can't find the right answer.

```
        $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM users" );
        $num   = $db->num( $query );
        while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {
            $active_ids = $array['id'];
        }

        $query = "SELECT u.username, u.habbo, count(*) AS n 
        FROM users u, timetable tt 
        WHERE u.id=tt.dj and u.id IN (".$active_ids.")
        GROUP BY tt.dj";

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr id='uren-table-row'>";
                echo "<td width='60px'><div style='height:50px;padding-top:25px;overflow:hidden;float:left;margin-top:-25px;'><img style='margin-top:-28px;float:left;' src='http://habmoon.org/moonstream/dj?habbie={$row['habbo']}&amp;head_direction=3&amp;direction=2&amp;size=b&amp;hb=img&amp;gesture=sml'></div></td>";
                echo "<td width='200px' style='padding:0 15px;'>", $row['username'] ,"</td>";
                echo "<td style='padding:0 15px;'>Heeft <b>", $row['n'] ,"</b> Uur gedraait deze week</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: it only show's 1 result but i need to echo all result's @DelmerNicholson

Comment: Do `var_dump ($query )` . What are the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `$active_ids` a CSL. Currently you overwrite the id(s) on every iteration so you only getting the last one. You also need it separated by commas so use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Try:

```
while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {
            $active_ids[] = (int)$array['id'];
 }
 $active_ids = implode(',', $active_ids);
```

Comment: You still need to define a `$active_ids` variable, otherwise it will throw a Notice.

Comment: @divix Not with the dynamic array assignment it wont. Demo: https://eval.in/460411 Concatenating, `.=`, would throw the notice because that is trying to join the previously undefined string.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad. But I still prefer variable definition on top :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `count(*) AS n` from your query. This will cause MySQL to return only 1 record.

You also have some errors in your first lines:

```
$active_ids = array();
while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {
    $active_ids[] = $array['id'];
}
```

You forgot to define `$active_ids` and add `[]`.

Comment: it's not counting the id's.. because when i use $active_ids = '1,3,4'; it works perfectly but i need it to be automated.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it Christian, if you will remove `count(*) AS n` from query then you will get all relative records back. If you don't want to count them at all, then don't append my second code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388764/how-can-i-make-a-table-while-fetch-assoc That's what counting the id's

Comment: Ok now I get you. Replace: `IN (".$active_ids.")` with `IN (".join(',', $active_ids).")` in your query.

Comment: hmm doesnt work
`$query = "SELECT u.username, u.habbo, count(*) AS n FROM users u, timetable tt WHERE u.id=tt.dj and u.id IN (".join(',', $active_ids).") GROUP BY tt.dj";`

Comment: The `count (*)` is fine here. He's doing a `GROUP BY` Still +1 cause you did spot the error